# mongodb push if key exists otherwise set array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If the Investment has deletedDocuments key exists, push the new item to the array, it works fine but
if the deletedDocuments key does not exist in Investment I want to set the item as array, but its setting a [] blank array in db, item values are not saved

```
      const deletedDoc = {
          _id: updatedInvestment.id,
          docType: 'CADocument',
          deletedBy: user,
          deletedDate: new Date()
        }


        if (updatedInvestment.deletedDocuments && updatedInvestment.deletedDocuments.length) {
          await Investment.updateOne(
            { "_id": updatedInvestment._id },
            { $push: { "deletedDocuments": deletedDoc } }
          );
               // this works fine

        } else {

          await Investment.updateOne(
            { "_id": updatedInvestment._id },
            { $set: { "deletedDocuments": [deletedDoc] } }
            // this is setting a blank array  [] in the db
          );

        }
```

Comment: Hello! Can you also share the Schema of your models please?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about two options here:

1. Using not in in the filter + push to add the deleted doc to the array.
2. Using the `$addToSet` operator.

1:

If you have defined `deletedDocuments` as an array of objects in your schema you could do something like the following:

```js
await Investment.updateOne(
    {
        "_id": updatedInvestment._id,
        // I'm supposing your deletedDocuments have an _id here
        "deletedDocuments._id": { $nin: [deletedDoc._id] }
    },
    { $push: { "deletedDocuments": deletedDoc } }
);
```

This will filter if the deletedDoc does not already exists, if it not, it will push it to the array.

2:

If you have defined deletedDocs as an array of docs ObjectIds instead of objects, you could use the `$addToSet` operator.

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

```js
await Investment.updateOne(
    {
        "_id": updatedInvestment._id,
    },
    // Be carefull here, you have to "insert" the deletedDoc's _id if your schema is an ObjectId array
    { $addToSet: { "deletedDocuments": deletedDoc._id } }
);
```

[$addToSet mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

[Not In mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)